# Maximal interval of solutions existence: $x'(t)=-x(t)+\sin x(t)+t^3$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

$x'(t)=-x(t)+ \sin x(t)+t^3$  in $\mathbb{R}$

I consider the function: $$ f(t,x)=-x+\sin x + t^3 $$
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\cos x-1$$

I see that:

$$\left| \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \right| < 2$$

So, the function $f$ is a globally Lipschitz-function, because the partial derivative (considering the second variable) is bounded.

For the global existence theorem, the maximal interval of  solutions existence  is $(-\infty,\infty)$

Is it correct?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that $\frac{\partial}{\partial x(t)} t =0$?

Comment: @GiovanniDeGaetano I have this doubt

Comment: with no initial condition?

Comment: @abel yes, with no initial condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here are some ideas i have. first we establish that $$\frac{dx}{dt} = -x + k + t^3 \tag 1$$ has the solution $x_k(t) =k+  ce^{-t}+ x_p(t)$ where $x_p(t)$ is a particular cubic polynomial solution of $(1).$ the solution exists for all $t.$

now, argue that the solution $x$ to $$\frac{dx}{dt}=-x+ \sin x+t^3 \tag 2$$ lies between the solutions $x_{-1}(t)$ and $x_1(t).$